# pgfplots : md5 but no pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I'm re-opening some documents I worked on 3 years ago. Everything was working fine (set size, colors, text, legend, externalize to pdf, reinput pdf figure to save computation time)

I'm using exactly the same document than before, but I'm not able to update ".pdf" files anymore. There's a ".md5" file that appears in my directory, but no ".pdf" file. When compiling I get "Process exited with error(s)" but no red warning message ... I'm quite lost ...

Could you tell me what could have gone wrong ? Here is the main document, the TesFigure code is rigthbelow

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
\newcommand{\external}[1]{\tikzsetfigurename{#1}}
\newcommand{\externalremake}{\tikzset{external/remake next}}
\newcommand{\externalfalse}{\tikzset{external/export=false}}

\definecolor{VertClair}{rgb}{0.592,0.71,0.235}
\definecolor{RougeFonce}{rgb}{0.753,0,0}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=2, yshift=-0.0cm}, xlabel style={yshift=-0.0cm}, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, yshift=0.0cm}, ylabel style={yshift=-0.0cm}, try min ticks=4, title style={yshift=0.0cm}, /pgf/number format/.cd, 1000 sep={}}
\setlength\figureheight{0.2\textheight}
\setlength\figurewidth{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\externalremake
\tikzsetnextfilename{TestFigure}
\input{TestFigure}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the Testfigure.tex document :

```
\pgfplotsset{ylabel style={text height=2em}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
xmin=0,
xmax=4100,
xlabel={$f$ [Hz]},
ymin=0,
ymax=80,
ylabel={$\Re(k_p)$ [rad/m]},
name=plot1,
legend style={at={(0.5,1.2)},anchor=south,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=VertClair,
line width=3pt,
solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
199.219 0\\
208.98465 0\\
218.7503 0\\
228.51595 0\\
238.2816 10.4818102991843\\
248.04725 10.7058724227101\\
257.8129 10.9391425787095\\
267.57855 11.1233032281827\\
277.3442 11.3565733841821\\
287.10985 11.5898435401816\\
296.8755 11.7647961571811\\
306.64115 11.9980663131805\\
316.4068 12.1945043392853\\
326.17245 12.3786649887585\\
335.9381 12.5628256382318\\
345.70375 12.746986287705\\
355.4694 12.9710484112307\\
365.23505 13.155209060704\\
375.0007 13.3884792167034\\
384.76635 13.5726398661766\\
394.532 13.805910022176\\
404.29765 13.9862339914519\\
};
\addlegendentry{McDaniel};

\addplot [
color=RougeFonce,
line width=0.8pt,
solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
199.219 9.5463806877398\\
208.98465 9.79194715237442\\
218.7503 10.0318922438826\\
228.51595 10.2666857179722\\
238.2816 10.4967419836201\\
248.04725 10.7224284961406\\
257.8129 10.944072609671\\
267.57855 11.1619672178418\\
277.3442 11.3763754320694\\
287.10985 11.5875344887954\\
296.8755 11.7956590338924\\
306.64115 12.0009439001414\\
316.4068 12.2035664691959\\
326.17245 12.4036886907204\\
335.9381 12.6014588169266\\
345.70375 12.7970128994806\\
355.4694 12.9904760869259\\
365.23505 13.1819637537857\\
375.0007 13.3715824869617\\
384.76635 13.5594309505943\\
394.532 13.7456006469687\\
404.29765 13.9301765881435\\
};
\addlegendentry{McDaniel + lissage};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
xmin=0,
xmax=4100,
xlabel={$f$ [Hz]},
ymin=-11,
ymax=1,
ylabel={$\Im(k_p)$ [rad/m]},
at=(plot1.right of east),
anchor=left of west
]
\addplot [
color=VertClair,
line width=3pt,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
199.219 -9.57512603494448\\
208.98465 -9.76043768847691\\
218.7503 -9.99554945097107\\
228.51595 -10.2678002777756\\
238.2816 -0.0168813928683789\\
248.04725 -0.0135051142947031\\
257.8129 -0.00982190130523863\\
267.57855 -0.0135051142947031\\
277.3442 -0.0110496389683935\\
287.10985 -0.0122773766315483\\
296.8755 -0.0156536552052241\\
306.64115 -0.0168813928683789\\
316.4068 -0.0168813928683789\\
326.17245 -0.0193368681946885\\
335.9381 -0.0214854091052095\\
345.70375 -0.0193368681946885\\
355.4694 -0.0202576714420547\\
365.23505 -0.0239408844315192\\
375.0007 -0.00982190130523863\\
384.76635 -0.0359113266472787\\
394.532 -0.0584710062077487\\
404.29765 -0.182472510186386\\
};
\addplot [
color=RougeFonce,
line width=0.8pt,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
199.219 0.0201186749462678\\
208.98465 0.0159246606167756\\
218.7503 0.0120013879324201\\
228.51595 0.00832306875198974\\
238.2816 0.00486705219845796\\
248.04725 0.00161334439087568\\
257.8129 -0.00145578357296117\\
267.57855 -0.00435611816486059\\
277.3442 -0.00710177077661633\\
287.10985 -0.00970540083186755\\
296.8755 -0.0121784031586447\\
306.64115 -0.0145310662741576\\
316.4068 -0.0167727068313912\\
326.17245 -0.0189117844034445\\
335.9381 -0.0209559999520366\\
345.70375 -0.022912380680296\\
355.4694 -0.0247873534626333\\
365.23505 -0.0265868086434011\\
375.0007 -0.0283161556766149\\
384.76635 -0.0299803718231377\\
394.532 -0.0315840449154816\\
404.29765 -0.033131411033116\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: You can try adding \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} to the preamble of the document, and remove \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}. But a real solution will require an actual document.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to the reduced file ;)

Comment: Note that we generally do not like going to external sites to get MWEs. Please update your question with the data for the MWE. The main reason for this request is so that your question will remain useful for others in the future. That link may easily become defunct in the future.

Comment: A MWE that is included would absolutely help here. For what it's worth, I downloaded the files and after commenting out `\usepackage{frcursive}` the example compiles without issues on a current TexLive 2019.

Answer (score 0):

With the given minimal example and running on TeXLive 2019 using

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test_document.tex
```

the following output is generated without errors or warnings:

[image]

Comment: Nice ! I'll have a look on TexLive tomorrow, but it doesn't work on TexMaker so far :/

Comment: Not working on my mac neither, I just don't get what is wrong :/

Comment: @user12377975: We can only help you if you provide some information such as error messages, the system you are using, etc.

Comment: Problem is that I got no error... Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I've tried an another computer. Still no figure but I got a compiling file ending with this (shorten path with [...]) :

(C:\[...]\kp_NIDA_14pts.tex
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -inter
action=batchmode -jobname "kp_NIDA_14pts" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{TESTFIGURE}
\input{TESTFIGURE}"' ========
runsystem(pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "kp_NIDA_14pt
s" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{TESTFIGURE}\input{TESTFIGURE}")...disabled (restricted).

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file C:/[...]/kp_NIDA_
14pts.tex): unknown type of image